# How can I create a DLL in C using Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

How can I create a DLL in C using Visual Studio, for a program written in C?

Would really appreciate if anyone could post any direct or forum-page-link for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some sources that will get you started : [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm),[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx). Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you will find [this information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx) of the Microsoft website interesting.

It explains how to [create and use a dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx). The most important thing is to create a **New project** and then select a **Win32 Console Application**. Afterwards, in the **Application Settings** page, under Application type, you have to select **DLL**.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project, you select the DLL project type at the start of the wizard.